# React Native end-to-end testing with Detox not printing number of tests passed or failed?

Tags: react-native, testing, end-to-end, detox

So recently we decided to go with Detox to do end to end testing of our react native app. Everything works fine but at the end we don't see the number of tests failed or passed.

The integration was done exactly as said in the documentation of detox. Let me know if you need to know anything else!

We see the final result like this but how many tests passed or failed does not get printed at the end. How can this be achieved? :

[image]